# Python Decorator Object Not Being Available

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I get

```
NameError: global name 'git' is not defined
```

for `git.add(log_filename)`. I don't understand why since `repo = Repo(ABSOLUTE_PATH)` and `git = repo.git` is called before `original_function = function(ABSOLUTE_PATH, GIT_WORKING_DIR, log_name, remove_logs)`. Shouldn't the `git` object be available to the called function?

I would like to utilize the decorator in this instance, since a separate function will be using similar functionality. How can I make this decorator work?

```
 def raw_git(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(ABSOLUTE_PATH, GIT_WORKING_DIR,
            log_name=None, remove_logs=None):
        try:
            repo = Repo(ABSOLUTE_PATH)
            git = repo.git
        except NoSuchPathError:
            raise Exception("Error in finding local git path!")
        original_function = function(ABSOLUTE_PATH, GIT_WORKING_DIR,
                log_name, remove_logs)
        return original_function
    return wrapper


@raw_git
def git_add_log(ABSOLUTE_PATH, GIT_WORKING_DIR,
        log_name=None, remove_logs=None):
    log_name = GIT_WORKING_DIR + "/" + log_name
    try:
        git.add(log_filename)
        git.commit(message="Removing oldest logs")
        git.push()
    except GitCommandError:
        raise Exception("There was an error with git command "
                "for removing oldest log(s)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` is a *local* name inside the wrapper function. It is not visible outside of that namespace, so not in `git_add_log`.

Give that function a `git` argument instead, and pass in the object when you call the wrapped function:

```
def raw_git(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(ABSOLUTE_PATH, GIT_WORKING_DIR,
            log_name=None, remove_logs=None):
        try:
            repo = Repo(ABSOLUTE_PATH)
            git = repo.git
        except NoSuchPathError:
            raise Exception("Error in finding local git path!")
        original_function = function(git, ABSOLUTE_PATH, GIT_WORKING_DIR,
                log_name, remove_logs)
        return original_function
    return wrapper


@raw_git
def git_add_log(git, ABSOLUTE_PATH, GIT_WORKING_DIR,
        log_name=None, remove_logs=None):
    log_name = GIT_WORKING_DIR + "/" + log_name
    try:
        git.add(log_filename)
        git.commit(message="Removing oldest logs")
        git.push()
    except GitCommandError:
        raise Exception("There was an error with git command "
                "for removing oldest log(s)")
```

Comment: I see...in this case, do I even need a decorator? I could just make a separate function and return that git object.

Comment: @dman: you don't *need* a decorator, but it could still be a helpful pattern to use, if you have a lot of functions that need the `git` object. But a separate function would make the function signature *for outsiders* easier to understand.